# How do I reduce the nesting of my code when dealing with nested Option types?

Tags: rust

I'm new to Rust and I'd like to reduce the nesting of my code. Take this C# code as an example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var obj = arr[i];
    if (obj != null)
    {
        var something = obj.Something;
        if (something == null)
        {
            if (i % 3 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

ReSharper suggests rewriting it to reduce nesting:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var obj = arr[i];
    if (obj == null)
        continue;
    var something = obj.Something;
    if (something != null)
        continue;
    if (i % 3 == 0)
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    break;
}
```

Is there way to do the same thing in Rust? If I have nested `Option<Option<Option<T>>>` and so on I should write something like:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 1..100 {

        if let Some(data) = some_data::get_some_data() {
            if let Some(result) = data.some_work(i) {
                if result > 80 {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        println!("{}", i);
    }
}

mod some_data
{
    pub struct SomeData {
        value : i32
    }

    impl SomeData {
        pub fn some_work(&self, i : i32) -> Option<i32> {
            Some(self.value + i)
        }
    }

    pub fn get_some_data() -> Option<SomeData> {
        Some(SomeData { value : 50 })
    }
}
```

this example is simplified, but it shows the core problem.

Comment: You can use the `and_then` method of `Option` to streamline the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things you could do. One option would be to use a match and `continue` in the `None` arm, similar to your C# code:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 1..100 {

        let data = match some_data::get_some_data() {
            None => continue,
            Some(data) => data
        };
        let result = match data.some_work(i) {
            None => continue,
            Some(result) => result
        };

        if result > 80 {
            break;
        }

        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Another thing you could do, as @Cecilio Pardo suggested, is use the `and_then` method of the `Option` type to chain your operations:

```
fn main() {
    for i in 1..100 {

        if let Some(result) = some_data::get_some_data()
                              .and_then(|data| data.some_work(i)) {
            if result > 80 {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```